Dates included on SumIfs formula do not change automatically after drag down
I've been working on a summary sheet and by far have suceeded computing the monthly costs and data through this formula:

sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=1/1/2024",B2:B,"<2/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=2/1/2024",B2:B,"<3/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=3/1/2024",B2:B,"<4/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=4/1/2024",B2:B,"<5/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=5/1/2024",B2:B,"<6/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=6/1/2024",B2:B,"<7/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=7/1/2024",B2:B,"<8/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=8/1/2024",B2:B,"<9/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=9/1/2024",B2:B,"<10/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=10/1/2024",B2:B,"<11/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=11/1/2024",B2:B,"<12/1/2024")
sumifs(A1:A,B2:B,">=12/1/2024",B2:B,"<1/1/2024")

where A1:A is where the column of data I wanted to sum per month like cost, price, etc.
B2:B is the column where dates from January to December is listed. (January 1 to December 31 of this year, so you can imagine there was like 365 rows)
1/1/2024 & 2/1/2024 is the month January to February I wanted to compute.
But the problem is I want to compute my data per months starting from January to February, February to March and so on per cell. So there should be 12 copy of this formula in different months a year.
But, the dates won't change if I drag down my formula. I have to manually set it to different months (2/1/2024 & 3/1/2024 or 3/1/2024 & 4/1/2024) which is time consuming bcs I have to do this for 50+ google sheets. Can anyone recommend anything on how to solve this. Thanks.
I expect to have 12 cells in a row consisting the formula I listed above, but I don't have to change the date as I drag it down as it should automatically change per cell. How can we do this? Need your help, please.

you can probably do this at once using the QUERY function. Can you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

Hi I edited my question with a sample formula of how I envisioned it to be.

There are several ways to do this. One option is-
=MAP(SEQUENCE(12),LAMBDA(x,SUMIFS(A2:A,B2:B,">="&DATE(2024,x,1),B2:B,"<="&EOMONTH(DATE(2024,x,1),0))))

Another option is to use QUERY() function.
=QUERY({A2:A,INDEX(EOMONTH(B2:B,0))},
"select Col2, sum(Col1) 
where Col2>1 
group by Col2 
label sum(Col1) '' 
format Col2 'MMM-YYYY'")



Hi @Harun24hr, It's nice to interact with you again, but unfortunately, the formula you provided is not aligned with what I needed. I've edited my question with the sample formula I envision of modifying for your reference. Thanks a lot!

@NicoleMarie In case of manually dragging the formula, use =SUMIFS($A$2:$A,$B$2:$B,">="&DATE(2024,ROW(A1),1),$B$2:$B,"<"&DATE(2024,ROW(A2),1)).

Wonderful! Works exactly how I wanted. Thank you so much Harun! <3
